# pytesseract not showing text in terminal

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, python-tesseract

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvTlZ.jpg)I have the following code to convert char and numeric digits from an image

```
import cv2 
import pytesseract

img=cv2.imread('/home/mubashir/jeh_Project/1.jpeg')
rgb_img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(rgb_img))
cv2.imshow('RGB_img',rgb_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I can view the image but the text is not printing in the terminal.

Comment: Is the code working for other images?

Comment: No. For all is just give me spaces in return

Comment: it means it is not able to detect the text. possible reasons: 1- rotated text 2- not pre-processed images

Comment: Yeah @YunusTemurlenk is right. Your image needs to undergo some preprocessing before it is given to pytesseract

Comment: @SrivatsavRaghu Ok, what kind of preprocessing? I also give the image. Can you look at the image and give me a possible solution? I will be very thank full to you.